# How to convert a string representation of unicode hex "0x20000" to the int code point 0x20000 in Java

Tags: java, unicode, codepoint

I have a list of String representations of unicode hex values such as "0x20000" () and "0x00F8" (ø) that I need to get the int code point of so that I can use functions such as:
char[] chars = Character.toChars(0x20000);

This should cover the BMP as well as supplementary characters. I cannot find any way to do it so would be glad of some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `NumberFormat` implementation, but easier than that you can do something like this:

```
String hexString = "0x20000";
int hexInt = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(2), 16);
String stringRepresentation = new String(Character.toChars(hexInt));
System.out.println(stringRepresentation);   //prints ""
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got 131072 so thought it was not correct but got the right answer with Character.toChars(131072);